# gradle executable jar can't include local jar dependencies

Tags: java, oracle, gradle, jar, executable-jar

***SOLVED***

WaitingDatabase.connect(WaitingDatabase.java:17)

```
// added this line
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
        DatabaseProperties.properties.getProperty("waiting_url_oracle"),
        DatabaseProperties.properties.getProperty("waiting_user_oracle"),
        DatabaseProperties.properties.getProperty("waiting_password_oracle")
);
```

---

(Sorry for bad english.)

I have to connect my oracle database, so I downloaded oracle jdbc driver and added in my dependencies. **It connected well when I run at intellij,** so I built executable jar file with gradle.

However, it couldn't connect to my oracle database. I think it was built without oracle jdbc driver file, because it is a local jar file.

How can I build with all of my dependencies?

If you need more information about my project to solve this problem, please let me know.

Thank you :D

---

build.gradle

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'App'
    }
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.20'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mariadb.jdbc/mariadb-java-client
    compile group: 'org.mariadb.jdbc', name: 'mariadb-java-client', version: '2.6.0'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple
    compile group: 'com.googlecode.json-simple', name: 'json-simple', version: '1.1.1'

    // oracle 11g jdbc driver
    compile files('lib/ojdbc6.jar')
}
```

cmd

```
{directory}> java -jar ./{jarFileName}.jar
```

error message

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@{address}:{port}:{sid}
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at WaitingDatabase.connect(WaitingDatabase.java:17)
        at App.connectDatabase(App.java:22)
        at App.main(App.java:5)
```

WaitingDatabase.connect(WaitingDatabase.java:17)

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
        DatabaseProperties.properties.getProperty("waiting_url_oracle"),
        DatabaseProperties.properties.getProperty("waiting_user_oracle"),
        DatabaseProperties.properties.getProperty("waiting_password_oracle")
);
```

file tree

```
- {root directory}
  - lib
    - ojdbc6.jar
  - src
    - main
      - java
        - App.java
        - WaitingDatabase.java
  - build.gradle
```

---

**ADDED**

db.properties

```
sleep-millisecond=1000

waiting_db=oracle

waiting_url_oracle=jdbc:oracle:thin:@{address}:{port}:{sid}
waiting_user_oracle={username}
waiting_password_oracle={password}

waiting_url_mariadb=jdbc:mariadb://{address}:{port}
waiting_user_mariadb={username}
waiting_password_mariadb={password}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you did is correct:

```
compile files('lib/ojdbc6.jar')
```

This will also work:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: '*.jar')
```

The advantage of this is that it will include all the jars in the lib directory without you having to do it manually.

ojdbc6.jar is meant for JDK 6, as stated [here](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/jdbc-drivers-12c-downloads.html).
If you are using > JDK 6, you might want to consider upgrading your ojdbc6.jar and most importantly you might want to check [this](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2016/09/javasqlsqlexception-no-suitable-driver-mysql-jdbc-localhost.html).

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But my problem hasn't been solved by that...

Comment: Can i see your application.properties?

Comment: I'll add at my post!

Comment: my oracle database is version 11g, so I downloaded [here](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/jdbcdriver-ucp-downloads.html). I think ojdbc6.jar is fit for my project.

Comment: Thank you! I found the answer in the link you gave. I added this line:
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");